# Transpose multiple data range

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck with the transpose selection criteria using the below code. Currently using as application.inbox for range selection for selecting the target range of data. But the problem arises when i select multiple range (using Ctrl), i'm only able to select only 3-4 data range in another excel(the code being in different excel than the working data range excel). But when i use the same vba-enable excel for selecting multiple data range, i can select many ranges simultaneously. Don't know where is the problem occurring.
i'm not getting any error message while selecting data from different excel, it just that the previous selection gets deselect.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Rng As Range
Dim rowIndex As Integer
xTitleId = "Transpose"
Set Range1 = Application.Selection
Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", xTitleId, Range1.Address, 
Type:=8)
Set Range2 = Application.InputBox("Convert to (single cell):", xTitleId, 
Type:=8)
rowIndex = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In Range1.Rows
    Rng.Copy
    Range2.Offset(rowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, 
Transpose:=True
    rowIndex = rowIndex + Rng.Columns.Count
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't really understand your issue.. is it that you cannot select more than 3-4 ranges in a sheet from another workbook? Also, this `other` workbook, is that macro enabled and has macro's?

Comment: Workbook1 is macro enabled and has the above code with action button. Workbook2 is were all my data sets are. I can't select more than 4 data range from workbook2. But if i regular copy paste the data into workbook1 and then hit the action button for range select , i'm able to select multiple ranges.

Comment: also if I copy the data sets from workbook2 and paste it in new workbook(not saved), the multiple range select macro works. Problem only occurs in workbook2 multiple selection.